# How to exclude this library 'im.zego:express-video:3.4.0' in JUnit RobolectricTestRunner?

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, mockito, robolectric

I need to implement JUnit RobolectricTestRunner in my project. I had used many libraries in my project. So, I got this error `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/xiaomi/mipush/sdk/PushMessageReceiver`

Any solution for this issue or how to exclude some libraries for `RobolectricTestRunner` test case.